# phoenix: show image from aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, phoenix-framework

I study the phoenix, create an application that loads the image on aws s3, and then displays it. I was able to upload the image to the cloud, but now it is not clear how to display it to the user on the page (I do not want to make public link to these images in the cloud). I was looking for information on this issue, but did not find anything useful.

From the clouds I get the file as binary data. Do I need to create some of these data is a temporary file that will be displayed on the page? I can display the image as base64, but I think this is not the best way. I would appreciate advice.

Comment: Why not just use the url you generated on s3?
as ```<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/myimage.jpg" />```

Comment: @Renews, I planned that these images will be private, and had no direct links to the cloud. But if there is no other way, you will have to do so

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already fetched the image to a binary, you can just send it directly to the client with the appropriate content type and the browser will render it as an image. For example, to fetch and send the png at `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png`:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  image = HTTPoison.get!("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png").body
  conn
  |> put_resp_header("content-type", "image/png")
  |> send_resp(200, image)
end
```

If you open this in your browser, you'll see the image being rendered correctly because of the `content-type` header.

Comment: And if I need to put on this page, not only the image but also other content? That is, the image must be in the body of the page along with the text, etc.